Is a cyclic relation symmetric?
The slide here prove that if a relation $R$ over a set $A$ is both reflexive and cyclic, then it is symmetric. The proof is as follows:

First, we'll prove that R is symmetric. To do so, pick any arbitrary a, b ∈ A where aRb holds. We need to prove that bRa is true. Since R is reflexive, we know that aRa holds. Therefore, by cyclicity, since aRa and aRb, we learn that bRa, as required.

I would like to know if I can prove that a relation $R$ over a set $A$ is symmetric if it is only cyclic. My attempt is as follows:
Consider any arbitrary $a,b,c\in A$ where $aRb$ and $bRc$ hold. By cyclicity, we know $cRa$ holds.  Substitute $c$ by $b$.  We obtain that $bRa$ holds.
Are there anything wrong with my proof?

Can you elaborate explicitly what you mean by "substitute $c$ by $b$"? In particular, how do you know that $aRc$ holds?

If we substitute $c$ by $b$, what we obtain is an "if" sentence saying that if $aRb$ and $bRb$ hold then $bRa$ hold. Since the premise $bRb$ may not hold, the conclusion "if $aRb$ then $bRa$" also may not hold.

Hint: there is a counterexample with just two elements.

@JeanAbouSamra I can find a counterexample with three elements.  Can you show the counterexample with just two elements?

@Ken_T Take ${a, b}$ with $a R b$ and no other relation.

Hint: Find a relation that is cyclic, but not symmetric.
Hence, there must be an error in your proof that any cyclic relation is symmetric.
As indicated in the comments, the "substitute $c$ by $b$" step is not valid, because

 we do not have $bRA$ and $cRb$ holds, which are required for us to continue.


I know there is something wrong but I am not sure where it is exactly located.  The cyclicity is defined as $\forall a \forall b \forall c (aRb \land bRc \to cRa) $.  Since the statement is true for any arbitrary a, b and c, I supposed that the special case where b=c should also be true.  I guess there is something wrong with my reasoning on the truthness of the special case but I don't quite get it.

@KenT Did you read Noiril's comment above? In particular the part about "the premise may not hold", like what I was saying here? $\quad$ FYI Your "special case where $b=c$" is trivially true, namely that $aRc \land cRc \implies aRc$ which holds even without the cyclicality condition.

For any ${\mathrel R}\subseteq A\times A$, cyclicity is defined as: $\forall a{\,\in\,} A\,\forall b{\,\in\,}A\,\forall c{\,\in\,}A~(a\mathrel Rb\wedge b\mathrel Rc\to c\mathrel Ra)$.
Cyclicity does entail: $\forall a{\,\in\,}A\,\forall b{\,\in\,}A~(a\mathrel Rb\wedge b\mathrel Rb\to b\mathrel Ra)$, or equivalently $$\forall a{\,\in\,}A\,\forall b{\,\in\,}A~(b\mathrel Rb\to(a\mathrel Rb\to b\mathrel Ra))$$
However, without reflexivity this does not entail symmetry: $\forall a{\,\in\,}A\,\forall b{\,\in\,}A~(a\mathrel Rb\to b\mathrel Ra)$.
By reason that when the relation is not reflexive, then: $\exists b{\,\in\,}A~\neg(b\mathrel Rb)$ .  So, for every $a$, there is always a member $b$ that may not guarantee $a\mathrel Rb\to b\mathrel Ra$ will hold.
Thus to construct a counterexample, take a set with a relation that is cyclic but which is neither reflexive nor symmetric.  For this, $A=\{\alpha,\beta\}, R=\{(\alpha,\beta)\}$ suffices.
